# MS Word style cannot set particular font size

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, styles, microsoft-word-2016

I have an MS Word document with a paragraph style. It has font size set to 10pt.
However, when I apply it to the text in the document (which has size of 12pt), the font size of this text does not change for some reason (it stays 12pt). But what's more interesting, when I change font size for the style to 9pt or 11pt, the font size of the text in the document does change! What's happening?..

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open [the example document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ukefdh8wr8zkvs1/style%20problem.docx?dl=0) in Word 2016
2. Select word "consectetur" in the first line
3. See how it has size 12 and associated style "Code sample"
4. Open "Modify Style" dialog for the "Code sample" style
5. See how it has font size set to 10pt
6. Change font size for the style to 9pt
7. Click OK on the dialog
8. See how size of the selected word changed to 9pt

The font is Courier New. If I set the size to 10pt explicitly, it works.

What the hell? What's so special about 10pt size? Why this particular size is ignored?

Comment: Does the same characteristics apply at greater zoom levels? That is, zoom to 200% and perform the test again.

Comment: Is it a TrueType font? Other fonts, such as System, have a limited number of sizes and cannot be scaled.

Comment: @fred_dot_u Yes, zoom does not matter.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik This is a simple Courier New. And of course if I set the size to 10pt explicitly, it works.

Answer (score 3):

Recreate the style as a Character Style, then it works.